# @JsonProperty to be used only for deserialization from JSON, not for serilization to JSON

Tags: json

I have the following POJO. It contains data about my airport.

```
class MyClass
{
  @JsonProperty("AirportCode")
  String airportCode;

  @JsonProperty("AirportID")
  Integer airportId;
}
```

The POJO objects are created using a JSON received from an API. the API sample output is like below.

```
[
 {
   "AirportCode": "BBA",
   "AirportID": 4276802,
 },
 {
   "AirportCode": "SCQ",
   "AirportID": 5325651,
 }
]
```

My code is to function as follows

```
void func()
{
   //Get JSON from API and convert to POJO
   //Do some processing on the POJO
   //Convert POJO into JSON and write to file
}
```

The file contents are as follows

```
[
 {
   "AirportCode": "BBA-IN",
   "AirportID": 4276802,
 },
 {
   "AirportCode": "SCQ-USA",
   "AirportID": 5325651,
 }
]
```

I however require the output to be in camel case (like the POJO)

```
[
 {
   "airportCode": "BBA-IN",
   "airportId": 4276802,
 },
 {
   "airportCode": "SCQ-USA",
   "airportId": 5325651,
 }
]
```

Is there anyway I can get @JsonProperty to be honored only during deserialisation to POJO and not during serialization to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to annotate getters and setters with different jsonProperty values? Directly it won't work but if you change the getter/setter name it should as both methods will be processed as if they belonged to different fields.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    String airportCode;

    Integer airportId;

    @JsonProperty("airportCode")
    public String getAirportCodeForJson() {
        return airportCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("AirportCode")
    public void setAirportCode(String airportCode) {
        this.airportCode = airportCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("airportID")
    public Integer getAirportIdForJson() {
        return airportId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("AirportID")
    public void setAirportId(Integer airportId) {
        this.airportId = airportId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize into a Dictionary and then camel-case all keys. Afterwards you'd be able to use it as intended.